# What is this low-growing lawn weed with small white flowers in Massachusetts?

Tags: identification, weed-control, weeds

Can anyone help me identify this? It's popped up in my lawn in early spring. I live in Massachusetts and this thing is everywhere. It covers the ground so well, I'm afraid it'll keep grass from coming in. The leaves are small, very low to the ground, and grow in thick bunches. It is really hard to pull up.  I'm not sure, but I think it produces a small white flower on a long stem.

<sub>*Click photo for full size image*</sub>

[image]
[image]

Comment: Definitely NOT oxalis - not sure what it is, if no one else names it I'll do some research - its not unattractive, but clearly not something you want in a lawn

Comment: I _think_ it's [Mouse-ear chickweed (_Cerastium fontanum_ aka _C. vulgatum_)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerastium_fontanum) but not 100% sure. Are the leaves hairy? Could you take a close-up photo of the flower?

Comment: Thanks, Niall! I think you've got it! The leaves appear to be hairy, and Google images for Mouse-ear chickweed definitely match. I'll try adding another photo, but I think this is it. Thanks again!

Comment: @NiallC. Want to go ahead and write an answer?

Answer (score 2):

As Niall noted in the comments, this is [Mouse Ear Chickweed (*Cerastium fontanum*)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerastium_fontanum). It's an annual cool season plant with a very wide range in temperate and cool climates with plenty of rainfall.

It often germinates in the fall, and blooms and sets seed in the mid-late spring after slow growth over winter. Plants that germinate in the spring will bloom and set seed at about the same time as well.

Because it's prolific and sets a lot of seed in good conditions, it has also become a garden/lawn weed in many areas. It is easy (although possibly time consuming) to remove it by hand, and I am also not aware of its resistance to any commercial herbicide.